# instance of parent Class not accessible from subclass? "does not exist in current context"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scoping, recursive-datastructures, octree

So I'm fairly new to all this. I've got the beginnings of a simple Octree implementation for a Unity project. This consists of an Octree parent class, an instance of it, and a OctreeNode subclass

I'm currently trying to access some cached public variables in an instance of Octree from the OctreeNode subclass but it's throwing "*The name 'oTree' does not exist in current context*".

Previously, I had tried to access these variables directly from the parent class, without having created an instance of it - this resulting in a different error of "*An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Octree.property'*" so I tried remedying it by instantiating the class.

Now that I check, it seems that the oTree instance isn't available anywhere except the constructor... My foundation in C# is fairly patchy so it's probably something rlly basic

Here the errors are in the last 3 methods - I've commented the lines that present the error.

```
public class Octree
{
    public OctreeNode rootNode;
    public List<OctreeNode> LeafNodes { get; private set; }
    public float MinimumWidth { get; private set; }
    public int MaxDepth { get; private set; }

    public Octree(Vector3 center, Bounds bounds, int capacity = 5, float minimumWidth = .5f, int maxDepth = 5)
    {
        Octree oTree = this;
        oTree.rootNode = new OctreeNode(center, bounds, capacity);
        oTree.MinimumWidth = minimumWidth;
        oTree.MaxDepth = maxDepth;
        oTree.LeafNodes = new List<OctreeNode>();
    }

    public class OctreeNode
    {
        public Vector3 Center { get; private set; }
        public Bounds Bounds { get; private set; }
        public List<Vector3> Members { get; private set; }
        public OctreeNode[] Children { get; private set; }
        public List<OctreeNode> CurrentNeighbours { get; private set; }
        public int Capacity { get; private set; }


        public OctreeNode(Vector3 center, Bounds bounds, int capacity = 5)
        {
            Center = center;
            Bounds = bounds;
            Members = new List<Vector3>(capacity);
            Children = null;
            CurrentNeighbours = null;
            Capacity = capacity;
        }

        public bool IsLeaf()
        {
            return Children == null;
        }

        private bool IsPotentialNeighbour(OctreeNode other, float searchRadius)
        {
            // Bounds Checks
        }

        private void BuildNeighbourList(OctreeNode node, float searchRadius = 1f)
        {
            foreach (OctreeNode otherLeaf in oTree.LeafNodes)   // Error: oTree non-existent?
            {
                if (node != otherLeaf) 
                {
                    if (IsPotentialNeighbour(otherLeaf, searchRadius))
                    {
                        node.CurrentNeighbours.Add(otherLeaf);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Initial Call
        private void BuildLeafNodeList()
        {
            List<OctreeNode> LeafNodes = oTree.LeafNodes;      // Error: oTree non-existent?
            OctreeNode root = oTree.rootNode;                  // Error: oTree non-existent?

            if (root.IsLeaf()) { LeafNodes.Add(root); return; }
            foreach (OctreeNode child in root.Children)
            {
                BuildLeafNodeList(child, LeafNodes);
            }
        }

        // Recursive Call
        private void BuildLeafNodeList(OctreeNode node, List<OctreeNode> LeafNodes)
        {
            if (node.IsLeaf()) { LeafNodes.Add(node); return; }

            foreach (OctreeNode child in node.Children)
            {
                BuildLeafNodeList(child, LeafNodes);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help/suggestions would be much obliged :)

Comment: You shouldn't have variables for `LeafNodes` - you should probably compute it when you need it. So make `BuildLeafNodeList` a function and return `IEnumerable<OctreeNode>`. And then a node shouldn't know about the tree itself, so you don't need a reference.

Comment: Since nobody else mentioned it... `oTree` is a local variable in the constructor. It doesn't exist anywhere else in the code, which is why you're getting errors. Local variables don't survive past their enclosing scope.

Comment: You are mistaking subclass and nested class. Subclass means inheritance, nested class means you are declaring a class within a class as to make it a subcontainer within that class. And then the mentioned issue is about local variable. Whatever you create within a {} only exists within those. So your oTree only exists in the ctor.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I've created a cut-down version of your code so that you can see how to traverse the nodes to build a set of leaf nodes.

```
public class Octree
{
    public OctreeNode RootNode { get; private set; }

    public Octree()
    {
        this.RootNode = new OctreeNode();
    }

    public Octree(OctreeNode rootNode)
    {
        this.RootNode = rootNode;
    }

    public class OctreeNode
    {
        private List<OctreeNode> Children = new List<OctreeNode>();

        public OctreeNode()
        { }
        
        public OctreeNode(IEnumerable<OctreeNode> children)
        {
            this.Children.AddRange(children);
        }

        public bool IsLeaf => this.Children.IsEmpty();

        public IEnumerable<OctreeNode> GetDescendantLeafNodes()
        {
            if (this.IsLeaf)
            {
                yield return this;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var child in this.Children)
                {
                    foreach (var leaf in child.GetDescendantLeafNodes())
                    {
                        yield return leaf;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have purposefully made the children a `private List<OctreeNode>` rather than an array. You can instantiate an empty list to represent leaf nodes rather than using `null` which has a habit of throwing `NullReferenceException`s, and you don't want external code changing the members of your tree.

Here's a sample tree:

```
var octree =
    new Octree(
        new Octree.OctreeNode(
            new Octree.OctreeNode[]
            {
                new Octree.OctreeNode(
                    new Octree.OctreeNode[]
                    {
                        new Octree.OctreeNode(),
                        new Octree.OctreeNode(),
                    }),
                new Octree.OctreeNode(),
                new Octree.OctreeNode(),
                new Octree.OctreeNode(),
            }));
```

When I call `octree.RootNode.GetDescendantLeafNodes()` I get the expected 5 empty nodes:

[image: emptynodes]

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for the slow reply. Good point with the nulling and the private scope. I'm not very familiar with the IEnumerable interface - why do we return it as such when Children is already a list that we could iterate through

Comment: Also, apart from the original errors and swapping to a private list, was there something wrong with the approach I took with the BuildLeafNodeList method?

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` lets us use all of the LINQ operators and it allows for `yield return` meaning a method can now effectively return zero or more values.

Comment: @Ferrick - the biggest complaint that I would have with your code is that you're building multiple lists that hold values that can be derived. It means you have to be super careful with your code not to create inconsistent lists. Sort of like having a list of numbers and a field that holds the sum of those numbers, and then you add a number to the list and forget to update the sum. That kind of inconsistency leads to all sorts of bugs.

Comment: Ah I see that makes sense. The reason I'm building the lists is for optimisation purposes - the leaf and neighbours list are built once per whatever update cycle, so that the members don't need to iterate over the entire tree to fetch neighbours, but you're right I'll need to be meticulous about when/how I rebuild them so that I'm not accessing an outdated version for example.